# Find the greatest and least values over an interval

Tags: calculus

> Find the greatest and least values of the function $f(x) = 4x^3 - 15x^2 + 12x$ on the interval $[-1, 1]$

So I tried to differentiate it until I got to the second derivative and then I factored and I got $6(4x-5) = 0$, and then I got $x = 5/4$ and $x = 0$? Is this correct, I assumed greatest and least values were related to maxima and minima.

Comment: The second derivative has only one zero. Also, you need the roots of the **first** derivative to find the maximum/minimum of a point. Also, you need to also look at the edges of the interval. I suggest you go re-read your notes or textbook to freshen up on how to solve this kind of problem...

Answer (score 3):

Since
$$
f'(x)=12x^2-30x+12=6(2x^2-5x+2)=6(2x-1)(x-2),
$$
$f(x)$ has a critical point at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. $f(-1)=-31$, $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{11}{4}$, $f(1)=1$, so maximum is $\frac{11}{4}$ and minimum is $-31$.

Comment: thank you so much i got -31 but i scrapped my answer because it was outside of the interval so i thought it was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Given the proposition

$f(x)=4x³-15x²+12x$ in the interval $[-1,1]$

POETIC RECIPE

At it derivative,we have:

$f'(x)=12x²-30x+12$

At stationary point,

$f'(x)=0$

$12x²-30x+12=0$

Solving quadratically,we have:

$x=2$ or $1/2$

At the interval $[-1,1]$, $2$ doesn't belong to the interval, therefore it's not considered

Then the considered intervals are:

$f(1/2)$; $f(-1)$; $f(1)$

Evaluating the respective function as we plug in function of $x$ in the general function,we have:

$f\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{11}4$

$f(-1)=-31$

$f(1)=1$

∴ The greatest value of $f$ in $[-1,1]$ is $11/4$ and it least value is $-31$.

COOKED!!!

"All I know is that I want to know something "